# Why svg fill can be assigned an array as its value? What will an array do for this case?

Tags: jquery, svg

I accidentally wrote a buggy code as:

```
$('rect#west1').css('fill',['red']);
```

However, it did work the same as

```
$('rect#west1').css('fill','red');
```

However, when I change it to

```
$('rect#west1').css('fill',[ 'blue', 'red']);
```

It fails to render.

Why?

Comment: Note, that the problem is not related to SVG, but rather jQuery